# create a deployment package for Webservice in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, web-services, clickonce, setup-deployment

I want to deploy my Webservice(*.asmx) on client server.
I need to develop deployment package which will install the virtual folders and deploy the service just like clickonce.
Could someone give me Visual Studio step by step guide to do it.

Thanks,
Kanaya

Comment: I think you can't really get a step-by-step guide because we don't really know all of your requirements. Also what have you done already? Are there things you don't get? This is probably a nice starting point: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13698/Visual-Studio-Setups-Web-Setup-Part-I (note that this is Visual Studio 2005, you probably have a newer version but it should work for most parts)

Answer (score 4):

Most people use Web Setup Projects if the Web Service is simple - any dependencies (e.g. .NET Framework Installation, IIS, SQL Server, a Database, etc) will need to be installed separately by someone in advance of that Setup being run.

For more sophisticated deployments where you want to ensure certain components are on the target machine (e.g. IIS) and if not there get them installed as part of the setup process, then you can use Web Deploy.

Here are some different ways you can do it.

1. Web Setup Project
2. Web Deploy
3. MSDeploy

Here are some guides on the above tools:

- http://blog.thinkoriginally.com/2010/02/16/visual-studio-2008-web-setup-project-web-deployment-project-and-msdeploy/
- http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy
- http://cromwellhaus.com/2012/05/build-once-msdeploy-all-over-the-place/

How to use Web Setup Project:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13698/Visual-Studio-Setups-Web-Setup-Part-I